# Why is it possible to update atomic variables concurrently without race condition in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

The following code works without race condition

```
AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(0);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

IntStream.range(0, 1000)
    .forEach(i -> executor.submit(atomicInt::incrementAndGet));
```

Here is the implementation of `incrementAndGet`

```
public final int incrementAndGet() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

We can see `current` is not synchronized or locked, after one thread get the `current` another thread might already update the `current`.

But it seems like atomic class avoids race condition some how.

Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: `compareAndSet()` uses locking.  In most implementations, `compareAndSet()` will execute a special instruction that does the locking in hardware (e.g., the CMPXCHG instruction on x86 hardware.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compareAndSet` sets the value (and returns true) if and only if the first parameter is equal to the `AtomicInteger`'s current value.
That is, if another thread had already changed the value, then `current` would not be equal to the current value, and the loop would run once more.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet(int,%20int)) of `compareAndSet(int expect, int update)`:

> Atomically sets the value to the given updated value if the current
>   value == the expected value.